# Comma as a decimal separator in sprintf in en_CA locale

Tags: php, string-formatting, printf

Is it possible to use the comma as a decimal separator in sprintf in en_CA locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sprintf is locale aware and will always use the current locale settings but you can [use number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this.

Comment: How to make decimals in optional and need to use decimal separator and thousands separator?