# PHP Replacing dot with comma's not working

Tags: php, format

I have this number format :

```
39289.95
```

And i want it to look like :

```
39289,95
```

My problem is that if i use :

```
str_replace('.', ',', $data)
```

or

```
strtr($data, '.', ',')
```

or

```
number_format($data, 2, ',', '')
```

I get

```
39289.00
```

I tried to cast the variable in string before using str function but no luck it always give me a 'dot' and 2 zeros at the end. How can i format my data to look like 39289,95 ?

Note that the data is coming from a odbc plugin, but i don't think it change anything. It does seems like an easy problem but all i tried was 'supposed' to work as i searched in many forum and stackoverflow questions but mine doesn't.
Thank you.

EDIT(full code):

```
while (odbc_fetch_row($r)) {


  printf("<tr class='ter%s' >",trim(odbc_result($r,1)));

  printf("<td> %s</td>",odbc_result($r,1));


  $data = odbc_result($r,2);

  $str = preg_replace('/\./', ',', $data);
  //$data = number_format($data, 2, '.', '');
  //$data = strtr($data, ".", ",");
  //$data = str_replace('.',',',$data);
  printf("<td align=right> %6.2f</td>",$str);

  echo "</tr>\n";
}
 }
```

Comment: `$number = 123.45; $number = str_replace('.', ',', $number);` works fine on my machine, please provide your full code, probably better with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: `$data = 39289.95;
echo number_format($data, 2, ',', '');`

Comment: Another case of assuming $data is passed by reference, rather than returned from the function call? There seem to have been more than average of those today

Comment: It looks like it's being converted back into an integer (then float) at some point. str_replace and number_format will convert int to string.

Comment: Full code added. The comments are the method i tried. Don't be folled by the $str in my printf i use $data with the other methods. Just so you know it's not a variable name error.

Comment: Don't try to format as a string yourself using preg_replace(), number_format() whatever; and then use print() as though it was still a float.... either just use printf() but make sure you've set locale; or use number_format and display it as a string

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in "printf" which convert string back to number with dot (.)

```
while (odbc_fetch_row($r)) { 

    printf("<tr class='ter%s' >",trim(odbc_result($r,1)));

    printf("<td> %s</td>",odbc_result($r,1));

    $data = odbc_result($r,2);

    $str = preg_replace('/\./', ',', $data);
    $str2 = sprintf("<td align=right> %6.2f</td>",$str);
    echo str_replace('.',',',$str2);
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here [Comma as a decimal separator in sprintf in en_CA locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696163/comma-as-a-decimal-separator-in-sprintf-in-en-ca-locale)

You don't have to chain `preg_replace`, `printf` and `str_replace`, just use `number_format` to format your number as needed:

```
...
$data = odbc_result($r, 2);
printf("<td align=right> %s</td>", number_format($data, 2, ',', ''));
echo "</tr>\n";
...
```

or

```
echo "<td align=right> ".number_format($data, 2, ',', '')."</td>";
```